# div with max-width to always fit snug with width of contents

Tags: html, css

Take a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tN6QE/2/

We have the CSS

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

with two scenarios. When the contents are less than 200px in width, the div will resize to fit snuggly with the contents, with exactly 10px between last word and the right border.

When the contents are greater than 200px, the div will always stay at 200px in width *even when the width of the word-wrapped sentence is less than 200px*. That is, the word that sticks out the farthest within the div will be greater than or equal to 10px from the right border. What I want is the div to resize so that it's always exactly 10px between the rightmost word and the border (while retaining the `max-width` and the text left-aligned).

I've tried playing with properties like `word-wrap`, `word-break` and `white-space`. Supplying a `width` property won't work as `max-width` will [override it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width).

Any ideas? Is this even possible? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried controlling the width with the item contained (i.e. add styling directly to the word wrapped sentence) and let the div size itself accordingly to the text?

Comment: While it will add some extra space between words to make things fit, [`text-align: justify;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) looks like it will mostly do what you want. The last line doesn't look like it necessarily is expanded with inter-word space, but I think that's part of the definition of "justified text". [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tN6QE/3/). There's also the MS-only CSS rule extension [`text-justify`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/text/textjustify.html).

Comment: I've tried making an inner div with `display:inline` like [so](http://jsfiddle.net/tN6QE/7/) but the parent div still sizes to 200px

Comment: @apj15243, not looking to justify the text, but thank you for that recommendation

Comment: @MusikAnimal I'm not quite sure of what you're looking for, then. Do you want the div to end up with different widths at each line of the contained text? Maybe give a fiddle that has altered, hardcoded values that ends up making a very specific example look like what you're looking for?

Comment: I don't think what you are looking for is possible. If you think about it, the reason the width gets set to 200px is because the text is longer than that. Therefore, it will stay at its MAX-WIDTH because the text is LONGER than the max. You can't tell the CSS to max at 200px when the text is longer, then shrink because it wrapped. The fact is that the text is longer than 200px and therefore the CSS will maintain its max width.

Comment: @ajp15243 [here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/tN6QE/9/) with a hard-coded width of 153px. The point is that the rightmost word should have exactly 10px between it and the border – hence I had to play around to find a good example, as it would depend on the wording – and the browser, probably. I'm using Chrome 29 Mac OSX and this example shows the desired 10px padding

Comment: Might not be quite what you're looking for, but how about using [CSS3 hyphenation](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html)? Wouldn't be quite snug, but would reduce whitespace: http://jsfiddle.net/tN6QE/10/

Comment: @SlightlyCuban – not what I'm after, but cool solution nonetheless! Was not aware of such properties

Comment: May I also note that the wrapping is solely based on the width and padding of its container. In this case, it goes to the max-width, then wraps based on that. There's no way for it to know what its width will be beforehand, it just knows to wrap when it hits the max-width + padding.

Comment: @Chad, so I suppose the only solution is with JavaScript, as with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tN6QE/13/)

Comment: Here's one with a little jQuery to solve your problem http://jsfiddle.net/tN6QE/12/

Comment: @Colin McGrath beat you to it, but thanks!

Comment: @MusikAnimal Ahhh just barely :D

Comment: Both those fiddles reflow the text - the "200px" is on the first line in the OP's example, but ends up on the second line in yours (at least with a font of 16px Times).

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle with the [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/tN6QE/16/)

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 200px;
    text-align:justify;    
}
div:after{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: As described, looking for solution with the text _left aligned_. Thanks anyway